# Safemode in Hadoop hdfs

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hdfs

I have started my hadoop using the following command

```html
sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

When i browse in the hadoop web interface. i get: safemode is on. So,
i have leave the safemode by entering :

```
hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave.
```

Now i can create and delete directories.
the problem is when i try to upload a file, it doesnt allow me to upload. why? 
I have used the following command

```html
bin/hdfs fsck /
```

And the output is :

> healthy

.

How can i resolve this?

Comment: Instead of asking another question with the same contents, please [edit] this one with updated information.

Comment: do you know why i cant upload my files?

Comment: Why don't you look at the logs and see?

Comment: actually my replication factor is 1.. is it because of this? because i was getting , corruped file warning when one of my datanode was off.